# CodePagesEncodingProvider does not exist С#

Tags: c#, кодировка

я выполнял задачу с кодировкой на онлайн-компиляторах и на VisualStudio. Но при каждой попытке скомпилировать код выдает ошибку: error CS0103: The name `CodePagesEncodingProvider' does not exist in the current context.
Как это можно исправить? Что-то не так в моем коде?

Условие задачи:
Требуется написать программу, которая определит тип предложения. Если в предложении есть вопросительный знак, то оно вопросительное. Если есть восклицательный, то предложение восклицательное. Если есть и то и другое, то оно вопросительно-восклицательное. Если ни того ни другого в предложении нет, то оно повествовательное. Если ко всему прочему в предложении есть хотя бы одна запятая, то оно еще и сложное.

Формат данных:
Входные и выходные данные содержат предложение в кодировке CP1251.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace task_c
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var enc1252 = CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance.GetEncoding(1252);
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            string output = "";
            bool vopr = false;
            bool voskl = false;
            bool slozh = false;
            foreach (char c in input)
            {
                if (c == '?')
                {
                    vopr = true;
                }
                else if (c == '!')
                {
                    voskl = true;
                }
                else if (c == ',')
                {
                    slozh = true;
                }
            }
            if (slozh)
            {
                output += "сложное ";
            }
            if (vopr && voskl)
            {
                output += "вопросительно-восклицательное";
            }
            else if (vopr)
            {
                output += "вопросительное";
            }
            else if (voskl)
            {
                output += "восклицательное";
            }
            else
            {
                output += "повествовательное";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(output, enc1252);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Установите Nuget пакет `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages`. Ну и да, вместо миллиона `if` напишите `input.Contains(string)` который возвращает `bool`, код читабельнее будет

Comment: `Encoding win1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251");`

Comment: В условии задачи не сказано, что текст должен вводиться с консоли. Читайте его из файла в нужной кодировке.